# Should a microservice call itself or call an internal function

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-core, microservices

I'm working on a old project for my company and I have found a strange code practice.

We have multiple APIs:

```
Account/CustomerInformations => Should return all information
Account/CustomerName => Return just name
Account/CustomerPhone => return just phone
```

In the code of function `CustomerInformations()` they are calling the other APIs of the same service (micro-service is calling itself) (Account/CustomerName, Account/CustomerPhone) which I found really strange, because I think that it's not a good practice.

After asking the Architect, the reason he gave is that it's the only reason to pass through the load balancer and make the call quicker.

[image]

I think that we should call a Task to do the work instead of calling the micro-service it-self.

What are the best practice in this kind of situation?

Comment: No need to call the other endpoints. CostumerInformations service must implement it own logic for fetching all required information instead depend upon other two microservices because other microservices have only specific functionality and specific purpose.Write your own query if data is from DB or call specific other microservice endpoint(Not your service endpoint) to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the current reasoning to not keep things internal, is to mitigate potential performance issues. If there were indeed performance issues in the past, than keeping things internal might not be the way to go and could in fact cause degradation of service performance.

You could opt to split out the CustomerInformation into its own microservice, which would in effect split the calls to CustomerName and CustomerPhone in much the same way, but without the need to call "itself".

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a no-brainer. That pull-all function needs to be refactored to pull all the data from the DB in one-go, using paging if needed, rather than offloading it to other endpoints in the same function. Every single time this service calls itself it is wasting time traveling through your network path, adding latency, and adding cost. Your architect is an idiot if he thinks "going through the load balancer" is going to make it quicker -- it's going to make it easier to be LAZY and not implement this correct

Comment: He explains his choice like this :
"The server my be busy pulling data, ... for the first demand so by calling the load balancer we are sure that we may call another server which is doing nothing." His idea is calling another server is better than calling functions in the same server. 

He's doing the same thing with other functions performing more complicated work like account balance calculation ect ...

Answer (score 0):

how's table structure look like?  if all Informations are reside in same table, then it may be good to use internal API.
There may be some missing Information, you may want to check if there is some way to introduce LocalOptimization or already there in code, that use smartly to identify whether to call Internal API or call external API.
just assuming but small code refactoring should help here.